# How to convert "date" in "chr" format to "date" format?

Tags: r, date

I read a csv file and notice R parse "Date Created" column in 'chr' format. Tried to convert it to 'date' format but failed. Appreciate your advice. [image: Read csv file & check date types]

[image: Conversion with as.Date() failed]

Comment: `f$\`Date Created\` <- as.Date(f$\`Date Created\`)`

Comment: @RonakShah I tried as.Date() method with "format" (refer screen with error message) but failed. I wonder is there a way to "turn off"/disable the data type auto conversion when read in csv file with read_csv()? Anyway, TQ for your reply.

Comment: Ddi you try what I have suggested in my comment above?

Comment: I already try as.Date() in different ways, pls refer to the screen shot with error message.

Comment: alright, i found the cure to this issue. by using ymd_* function in "Lubridate", i can easily convert the character to datetime format.